# Qual a origem da expressão: "quem tem filhos, tem cadilhos"?

Tags: significado, expressões, português-europeu, origem-histórica

Qual a origem da expressão: "Quem tem filhos, tem cadilhos"?

Quais os primeiros registos da sua utilização?

cadilhos=problemas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esse provérbio já vem numa obra do século XVII, a [*Feira do Anexins*](https://books.google.pt/books?id=1ZRFAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA105&dq=%22tem%20cadilhos%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi9q8DSzu3oAhUCXRoKHbFCA90Q6AEIXTAF#v=onepage&q=%22tem%20cadilhos%22&f=false) de Francisco Manuel de Mello (1608-66, [Wikipédia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Francisco_Manuel_de_Melo)). Deixo aqui com algum contexto, mas macacos me mordam se eu compreendo alguma coisa, porque as personagens falam só com provérbios e trocadilhos:

> — Bem sabemos, que não quer cag… maçarocas; por isso não come *fiado*
>   — Folgo que lá se embaracem; que eu por um triz, que não desconfio; e era capaz de dar dous pannos.
>   — Agora, **quem tem filhos tem cadilhos**: vossê não havia de chegar a esses termos.

Dois dicionários de 1836 e 1842 explicam que *cadilhos* são uns fios que ficam soltos na borda dos tecidos acabados de tecer, e também franjas e coisas assim; e daí a ideia de coisa pendurada. O primeiro dicionários curiosamente tem a versão “quem não tem filhos tem cadilhos” (não tens filhos, tens outros dependentes):

> CADILHOS […] fios primeiros do urdume que não levão teage de fios atravessados, e que ficão soltos quando se cortão as têas; franja, v. g. das alcatifas , franja de fio de ouro ou prata; fios de borla de doutor, fios pendentes. ***Quem não tem filhos tem cadilhos***, prov., dependentes, pessoas a seu cargo.
>   [Francisco Solano Constancio, *Novo Diccionario Critivo e Etymologico da Lingua Portugueza*, Paris, 1836](https://books.google.pt/books?id=HM9TAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA202&lpg=PA202&dq=%22tem%20filhos%20tem%20cadilhos%20,%20prov%22&source=bl&ots=HUzT9edpPt&sig=ACfU3U39L774mrEvqnE3-wCYCH7XaGeztA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj18q7Qz-3oAhUa4OAKHXApD4YQ6AEwAHoECAMQKQ#v=onepage&q=%22tem%20filhos%20tem%20cadilhos%20%2C%20prov%22&f=false)

O de 1842 dá um enfoque um nadinha diferente:

> CADILHO […] guedelha comprida a modo de franja na extremidade das toalhas, guardanapos, alcatifas, sanéfas etc. it. acessórios, anexos no sent. fig. por isso daqui vém o prov. “**quem tem filhos tem cadilhos**.”
>   [Antonio Maria do Couto, *Diccionário da maior parte dos termos homónymos, e equívocos da lingua portugueza*, Lisboa, 1842](https://books.google.pt/books?id=IwcoAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA35&dq=%22tem%20cadilhos%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi9q8DSzu3oAhUCXRoKHbFCA90Q6AEIRzAD#v=onepage&q=%22tem%20cadilhos%22&f=false)

Esta ideia, dos filhos como coisa pendurada lembra-me *pingente encardido*, que eu já tenho ouvido pais chamar às crianças ([*pingente* (Priberam)](https://dicionario.priberam.org/pingente) é coisa que pende).

Mas dois artigos na Revista Lusitana de 1908 e 1911 (podes obtê-los na [Biblioteca Digital Camões](http://bibliotecasicl.pt/Opac/Pages/Search/Results.aspx?SearchText=Revista%20Lusitana&DataBase=105199_GLOBAL&Operator=AND&Profile=Default)) vão num caminho diferente. O artigo de 1907 (vol. X, p. 83) diz que com os cadilhos dos tecido acabados de tecer se fazem barbantes, e daí “a significação metaphorica de «embaraços»”. O de 1911 (vol. XIV, p. 150) corrobora: diz que no Minho, *cadilho* se usa na “acepção de «amarrilho» = fio para prender” e que é “nesse sentido que o termo entra no provérbio : «Quem tem filhos tem *cadilhos;*» isto é «prisões, peias, cuidados.»

Comment: As personagens falam só com provérbios e tro... cadilhos?

Comment: @ANeves, bem observado. Uma pessoa mesmo sem querer, lá vai cair neles...